# JPA 3 level inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa

First of all I've been all the morning seeking for a solution for my problem. I've found similar problems but no one fixed my problem :(

I have a 3 level inheritance on my Java classes model:

```
A <-- B <-- C
```

Mapping this into a Relational Data Base I've made
`A (1) -- (0..1) B (1) -- (0..1) C`, so my annotated Java classes are something like:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@XmlRootElement
public class A implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idA;
    private Integer type;
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="idB", referencedColumnName="idA")
@XmlRootElement
public class B extends class A implements Serializable{
    private Long idB;
    private Integer type;
    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idB") 
    private A a;
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("8")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="idC", referencedColumnName="idB")
@XmlRootElement
public class C extends class B implements Serializable{
    private Long idC;
    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idC") 
    private B b;
    ...
}
```

I don't know why, invoking a Query `SELECT c FROM C c` retrieves me `0` result when I have info on that table. If I do the query `SELECT b FROM B b` it works fine. It seems to be something wrong with the hierarchy annotations I've used.

Any idea? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You need to use strategy for your B and C and take FK from these to your A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joined table inheritance means that when you have a C entity, there must be a row in the A, B AND C tables.  If you have data in C but no corresponding data in A or B that match up, then you will get no C entities back - the data is invisible to JPA because it first queries the A table to see if there are rows with a Type=3, and then joins it to B and C.

So check that your java inheritance model actually matches the data model.  You also show that B and C have a reference to their parent - this cause the same id field to be mapped twice, as it is in both the Entity's PrimaryKeyJoinColumn and the mapping's JoinColumn.  Since the referenced A (or B) is apart of the B (or C), there is no need to also have an object referenence to it - any of the inherited get methods will return the data from the A table anyway.

Comment: Thank you! I finally fixed it. The problem, as you say, was I had different types for the 2nd inheritance level and 3rd, the rows i wanted to have in the 3 tables i had something like: A.type=1, B.type=2, so as you said, it reads first from A, he can match it with B, but due to C is not type 1, it can't be reached from A. Now I have A.type = B.type = 1... Thank you again!

Comment: I mean, the code I posted wasn't wrong, just changing that column value in the DB it works